# Java - onFormClosing conversion C# to Java

Tags: java, c#, language-concepts

I would like to ask if someone can help me with the following: I am trying to complete the following in Java. I am still quite new to Java and I hope that this can be achieved. Please note that this C# code might not be 100% correct, but I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
//C#
//Form one
public void onFormShown(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.User == null)
    {
        frmTwo f = new frmTwo();
        f += f_onFormClosing(EventArgs e);
        this.Hide();
    }
}

private void f_onFormClosing(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Show();
    this.User = f.User;
}

//frmTwo
private void btnClose_Click(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

EDIT:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    if (loginUser.get().getUserLogin() == null) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Where loginUser is private AtomicReference<Singleton>
                //loginUser = new AtomicReference<Singleton>();
                //The reason for the data type here is to pass
                //the object by reference, log the user in and change
                //the value of the Main form's variable
                LoginForm login = new LoginForm(loginUser);
                login.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                        //here I need to place the logic of
                        //setting the Main form's 'loginUser'
                        // object to the value generated in
                        //the Login form
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Where's your attempt at converting it and what's the problem? 2. State which framework(s) you are using, the languages themselves don't create forms

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: Also it is not really a specific problem with the code that I have, I am just not sure how to accomplish the stated behavior in Java